# For loop for drawing images

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html5-canvas

Everything else in my game works except for the floor. Does anyone know why this doesn't work.

```
var floor = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById('bg');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let posYFloor = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    floor[i] = new Image();
    floor[i].src = "Bricks.png";
    floor[i].onload=function() 
    {
        ctx.drawImage(floor[i],i*50,posYFloor);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would depend on what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! Please be more specific about what is not working, explain what you intend to happen and what is actually happening. Are there errors etc.

Comment: Your image isn't loaded, draw the image in the onload event, define that event before assigning the src.

Comment: @CasparKleijne Thanks, that might be the issue

Comment: @ScottHunter The problem was that the images were not loading

Comment: @CasparKleijne As you can see from the edited code on the question, I have the onload event, but there might be something wrong with it

Comment: define that event !before! assigning the src

Comment: @CasparKleijne I tried that and it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I realised that I didn't even need floor[i] at any point and I had a separate setInterval.

```
var floor = [];
var canvas = document.getElementById('bg');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let posYFloor = 0;for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
    floor = new Image();
    floor.src = "Bricks.png";
    floor.onload=function() 
    {
        ctx.drawImage(floor,i*50,posYFloor);
    }
  }


setInterval(function() {
        for(let i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            ctx.drawImage(floor, i*50, posYFloor);
        }
    },1);
}
```